# Quick way to find out all the keys of a repeated hash value

Tags: ruby, hash

I have a hash as follows:

```
hash = {"Monday" => "a", "Tuesday" => "b", "Wednesday" => "c", "Thursday" => "b", "Friday" => "c"}
```

I want to get a new hash which will be:

```
{"a" => "Monday", "b" => "Tuesday, Thursday" , "c" => "Wednesday, Friday"}
```

`Hash#invert` just gives the first value and loses the repeated ones. Any efficient way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
result = hash.inject({}){|m, kv| m[kv.last] ||= []; m[kv.last] << kv.first; m}
```

This will give you a hash in the form:

```
{"a" => ["Monday"], "b" => ["Tuesday", "Thursday"] , "c" => ["Wednesday", "Friday"] }
```

If you absolutely need them as a comma separated list, you can join them afterwards:

```
result = Hash(*result.map{|k, v| [k, v.join(', ')]})
```

Or append them on the first iteration:

```
result = hash.inject({}) do |m, kv| 
  if m[kv.last]
    m[kv.last] << ", " 
  else
    m[kv.last] = ""
  end
  m[kv.last] << kv.first
  m
end
```

Answer (score 3):

```
hash.inject({}){ |h, (k,v)| (h[v] ||= []) << k; h }
=> {"a"=>["Monday"], "b"=>["Tuesday", "Thursday"], "c"=>["Wednesday", "Friday"]}
```

Answer (score 0):

A functional approach using a couple of abstractions from [Facets](http://rubyworks.github.com/facets/):

```
require 'facets'
hash.map_by { |k, v| [v, k] }.mash { |k, vs| [k, vs.join(", ")] }
#=> {"a"=>["Monday"], "b"=>["Tuesday", "Thursday"], "c"=>["Wednesday", "Friday"]}
```

Answer (score 0):

`each_with_object` is an alternative approach, not sure if I can somehow get rid of the ternary . . .

```
 hash.each_with_object({}) { |kv,new_hash| k,v = kv; new_hash[v] = new_hash[v] ? new_hash[v] + ',' + k : k}
 => {"a"=>"Monday", "b"=>"Tuesday,Thursday", "c"=>"Wednesday,Friday"}
```